# Kotlin ?.let + ?:run + CompletableFuture unexpected behaviour

Tags: kotlin, completable-future

Here is the code, it runs as expected, no exception

```
fun main() {
    var mayBeEmptyString: String?

    mayBeEmptyString = "1";

    mayBeEmptyString?.let {        
        println("Inside let")
    } ?: run {
        throw RuntimeException("Inside run")
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Inside let
```

And here is the code that I am not able to understand how it works:

```
fun main() {
    var mayBeEmptyString: String?
    mayBeEmptyString = "1";
    mayBeEmptyString?.let {
//        println("Inside let")
        CompletableFuture.runAsync{ println("Inside let")}.join()
    } ?: run {
        throw RuntimeException("Inside run")
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Inside let  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Inside run  
at com.test.TestKt.main(test.kt:15)  
at com.test.TestKt.main(test.kt)
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runAsync` is meant for running a task that doesn't return a value, so you get a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, and attempting to read its value with `get` or `join` will give you `null`.

You then make this `null` result of `join` the result of your `let` block, which will cause your `run` block to be executed.

Comment: In a way, yes. The safe call operator `?.` means that if `mayBeEmptyString` is `null`, then the `let` block won't even be executed and instead `null` will be returned. Your elvis operator (`?:`) at the end just checks whether the result is `null`, regardless of how you ended up with that result.

Answer (score 0):

Because `CompletableFuture.join()` return null value cause

```
mayBeEmptyString?.let {
//        println("Inside let")
        CompletableFuture.runAsync{ println("Inside let")}.join()
    }
```

will be null
and `run {  }` will be executed